# Intellisence: view file as browser JavaScript, not Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I'm using the Node.js tools for visual studio plugin on my current project. Since node is Javascript, it thinks any js file is node, when in fact, some it is for the browser (client). I want to "tell" visual studio to recognize these client js files for what they are.... how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution, Pio's answer is valid, but I couldn't find a "JavaScript Html & CSS" project that wasn't tied to asp, so I found a better, but slightly annoying solution.

It simply requires editing the project file (`Name.njsproj`), and then editing the tags under `<ItemGroup>`:

It will look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile  Include="client\js\foo.js" />
    <Compile  Include="client\js\bar.js" />
    <Compile Include="client\js\fiz.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Simply changing the `Compile` to `Content` will fix the issue

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="client\js\foo.js" />
    <Content Include="client\js\bar.js" />
    <Content Include="client\js\fiz.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The annoying downside is that every client file one adds, the project needs to be manually updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two projects, one for client side and one for the back-end. If you make the two projects part of one [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx) I think you've got your answer.

**UPDATE**

So if I understood right you want an application where *Intellisense* will give you auto-complete options for `js` in one folder in and another one for `node`.

You can do this the following way: you create a Solution (every project is part of a solution; solutions can contain multiple projects, it's just a matter of organizing your code) for a NodeJS project (using the plugin you mentioned).

After that it is straight forward: you just need to create a folder let's say `public` where you put your client side code. There you add your `JavaScript` by adding simple `js` files. See the image below:

[image: adding js file] [image: js with intellisense]

Comment: Do you think you could add steps... no one else seems to be offering a better solution

Comment: Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/23x5fk78(v=vs.100).aspx) with detailed descriptions. Let me know if you don't manage.

Comment: Thanks for you help, +1, but I found a solution that helps me more.